# Can I use glVertexAttribPointer instead of glVertexAttribIPointer

Tags: opengl

[A tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html) I read specifically advocated using glVertexAttribIPointer for integer data, uploading data into a ivec4 data type in the shader.

I was wondering why I can't use glVertexAttribPointer with the GL_INT data type instead. Why will it corrupt my data? Reading the API reference gave no clue to this.

Comment: corrected the mistake.

Comment: it seems like a duplicate, but my question will get more hits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked at the OpenGL 3.3 (Core Profile) spec, and all I could find was this wording on page 29:

> Data for an array specified by **VertexAttribPointer** will be converted to floating-point by normalizing if normalized is `TRUE`, and converted directly to floating-point otherwise. Data for an array specified by **VertexAttribIPointer** will  always  be  left  as  integer  values;  such  data  are  referred  to  as pure integers.

I couldn't find any explicit mention that there would be error checking, unspecified values, or undefined behavior, but presumably, if your attribute array converts integers to floating-point, but your shader takes integers, you'll end up with incorrect attribute values.

I know that very old hardware was used floating point everywhere, so `ivec4` would just be `vec4` in disguise.  Therefore, even if this works on your hardware, you shouldn't do it.

**Summary:** Don't do it.

Comment: For the OpenGLES spec `VertexAttribIPointer` isn't available, so I have resorted to using `glVertexAttribPointer(..., ..., GL_INT,...` for passing ints to the shader as an `in vec4` which then I am doing a piecewise int cast, and it seems to be working on my driver, is this what you mean when you say *even if this works on your hardware, you shouldn't do it.* or were you talking specifically about `ivec4`? Thanks.

Comment: @gothere: Yes, you can use `GL_INT` with `glVertexAttribPointer`—but like you say, the input type is then `vec4` (a floating-point type) and not `ivec4` (the integer type). The purpose of `glVertexAttribIPointer` is so you can use `ivec4` and other similar input types.